# Returning HTTP Error Status Code with Image Content

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-status-codes

I'm working on an API that would return an image. In case any error is encountered in the API, though I can issue a HTTP - 500 response (or similar error codes) with text content or no content at all, I need to be able to return an Image Content with the error represented inside the image itself. In other words, when any error is encountered, I create an image representation of the error text and return the image, with the http status code at as 500 - Internal Server Error.  I'm using ASP.net Web API and I'm able to create a HTTP 500 Response with Image content and mime type as "image/jpg".

Http 500 with plain text response:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Length: 14
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Mon, 24 Jul 2017 06:43:55 GMT

Error Occured!
```

Http 500 with Image Content:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Length: 622485
Content-Type: image/jpg
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Mon, 24 Jul 2017 06:44:56 GMT


<<ImageContent>>
```

Though it is possible, I need to know if this approach is OK as per the best practices of web API or not. Thanks.

Comment: You could add an error handler (which is global), or in the action method return the image in its exception handler.

Comment: Thanks Richard. But unfortunately you didn't answer for the question. I need to know if this approach of sending image in error response is OK

Comment: Will it work: depends on your clients (which I cannot comment on). For a general WebAPI (ie. 3rd party clients) then I would say it is bad: normally an API consumer will be code and it is hard to get data from an image.

Answer (score 0):

Best-practice ("everybody does it") is to return HTML, with a `Content-Type: text/html`, even if the request was for an image.

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to this site [here](https://jamessdixon.wordpress.com/2013/10/01/handling-images-in-webapi/)

Below you can take look at piece of code from shared link:

```
var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
String filePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Images/HT.jpg");
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
Image image = Image.FromStream(fileStream);
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
image.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(memoryStream.ToArray());
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");

return result;
```

Comment: Thanks Gino,Updated my comment. My bad I will take note of it for future.